# I'm getting unresolved external symbol winrt_make_* when trying to compile C++/WinRT blank app from XamlApplication

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-winrt

I am trying to follow the tutorial here: [UWP Xaml Hosting API.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/using-the-xaml-hosting-api#host-a-custom-uwp-control)

I am at the part of the tutorial where I'm supposed to create a blank app that defines a `XamlApplication` application. I have defined it in my header (.h) as:

```
#pragma once
#include "App.xaml.g.h"
namespace winrt::UI_Host::implementation
{
    struct App : Microsoft::Toolkit::Win32::UI::XamlHost::XamlApplicationT<App>
    {
        App();
        ~App();
    };
}
```

My .cpp file has it defined as:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "App.h"
using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::ApplicationModel;
using namespace Windows::ApplicationModel::Activation;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation;
using namespace UI_Host;
using namespace UI_Host::implementation;

winrt::UI_Host::implementation::App::App()
{
    Initialize();
}

winrt::UI_Host::implementation::App::~App()
{
    Close();
}
```

If I leave my .IDL file as:

```
namespace UI_Host{}
```

It compiles fine, but I can't use the `App` class in my Win32 Program. So I changed the IDL file to this:

```
namespace UI_Host
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass App : Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.XamlHost.XamlApplication
    {
        App();
    }
}
```

But now it won't compile. The error I get when compiling is this:

```
>module.g.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl winrt_make_UI_Host_App(void)" (?winrt_make_UI_Host_App@@YAPEAXXZ) referenced in function "void * __cdecl winrt_get_activation_factory(class std::basic_string_view<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t> > const &)" (?winrt_get_activation_factory@@YAPEAXAEBV?$basic_string_view@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@@std@@@Z)
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: You forgot to `#include "App.g.cpp"`, as [explained here](https://kennykerr.ca/2019/06/07/cppwinrt-optimizing-components/).

Comment: ... or [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190606-00/?p=102546), for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++/WinRT 2.0 introduced a breaking change in order to support [Optimized Components](https://kennykerr.ca/2019/06/07/cppwinrt-optimizing-components/). It is used when passing `-optimize` to cppwinrt.exe. This option is enabled by default for new projects.

The breaking change requires component authors to `#include` a generated implementation file into the compilation unit that implements that particular type. In your case, you need to `#include "App.g.cpp"` into *App.cpp* (make sure to `#include` it after the header file *App.h*).

To allow your code to compile with and without the `-optimize` flag, you can conditionally include *App.g.cpp*:

```cpp
#include "App.h"

#if __has_include("App.g.cpp")
#    include "App.g.cpp"
#endif
```

For easy to digest lessons you can read Raymond Chen's blog entry titled [Why does my C++/WinRT project get errors of the form "Unresolved external symbol `void* __cdecl winrt_make_YourNamespace_YourClass(void)`"?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190606-00/?p=102546).

Comment: Along with adding the missing info that was left out on the Microsoft Docs page, and only shown in the sample project this works. Thanks!.